# Rails: Disable CSRF for a 3rd party POST Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, csrf, http-post

I have a Rails 3.2 App where I need to accept POST requests from a 3rd party.
I want to store the incoming requests in my 'message' model.
My MessageController looks as follows:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create
...

def create
@message = Message.new(content: params[:content], command: params[:command], messageId: params[:messageId], ...)

respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
...
```

The requests I'm receiving look like this:

```
curl -d "content=GUESTTEST&command=deliverMessage&messageId=11389622" https://[myapp].herokuapp.com/messages
```

This works fine locally (http://localhost:3000/messages) but as soon as I switch to heroku, the requests don't work anymore.

```
heroku logs
```

says:

```
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/" for 178.195.215.59 at 2012-08-13 07:54:01 +0000
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"content"=>"GUESTTEST", "time"=>"2012-08-01 10:09:03", "businessNumber"=>"5555", "sessionId"=>"5555CHS1343808543654", "operatorCode"=>"99999", "msisdn"=>"0099955291", "keyword"=>"GUESTTEST", "command"=>"deliverMessage", "messageId"=>"11389622"}
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2012-08-13T07:54:01+00:00 heroku[router]: POST guestlist12.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=72ms status=200 bytes=2425
```

What do I need to change to allow the posts to work without the CSRF token?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: do you have protect_from_forgery left in application controller?

Comment: yes I do, should I modify that? If I remove it from the application controller, I do have to add it to every other controller, right?

Comment: I've tried that and disabled it in the application controller but it didn't solve the problem. Any other idea?

Comment: It actually did, the problem was somewhere else. thanks for your help!

Comment: @AmolPujari - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> [Remove] protect_from_forgery [from the] application controller.

~ answer per [Amol Pujari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477403/amol-pujari)